# Vaadin flow-frontend doesnt copy tsx files

Tags: typescript, vaadin, vaadin-flow, tsx

I have a tsx File in ressources but it doesnt get copied into flow-frontend. Webpack and tsconfig are correctly configured - is there something I need to tell Vaadin for it to add the tsx file?

Comment: where exactly are these files located?

Comment: For the historical record, the issue was reported (https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13318) and fixed (https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/13323).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment by @Tarek Oraby - this was fixed in Vaadin 23.0.3.